# Numpy from string (Difference of uint8 and uint16) [Combining two uint8 values to one uint16 value]

Tags: java, python, numpy, binary, hex

I have an audio file in Java, when I read `AudioInputStream` and convert it to byte array, I get values between `-128` and `127`. I need to convert those values to a range between `-32768` and `32767`. So I think I need to combine every two values in my Java array to a single value.

In Python, I can read the file and I can convert it to string by `numpy.fromstring` function. Assume I store `uint8` values in A, `uint16` values in B.

`A[2*i] = -50`

`A[2*i+1] = 21`

`B[i] = 5582`

I have values like this. Somehow I think I need to combine every two values in A to be able to have B. How can I do that in Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`ByteBuffer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html):

```
byte[] b = { 37, -39, -112, -32, 123, -40, -114, 121 };
short[] s = new short[b.length / 2];
ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.wrap(b);
// buf.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++)
    s[i] = buf.getShort();
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(b));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s));
```

Output (big-endian, the default):

```
[37, -39, -112, -32, 123, -40, -114, 121]
[9689, -28448, 31704, -29063]
```

Output (little-endian, by uncommenting the line):

```
[37, -39, -112, -32, 123, -40, -114, 121]
[-9947, -8048, -10117, 31118]
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick and great answer.